# Find directed spanning tree of unweighted directed graph in $O(|V| + |E|)$

Tags: algorithms, graphs

A directed tree (also called an arborescence) of $G$ is a directed subgraph of $G$ in which there exists a vertex $v$ such that there is a unique path from $v$ to every other vertex in the graph.

Please help with an $O(|V| + |E|)$ algorithm that finds a directed spanning tree in $G$ or notifies if there is none.

Comment: Could you please give reference to where you find this problem. It seems a standard problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an arborescence exists in $G$, its root must be a node in a strongly connected component with in-degree $0$, as any node inside it is unreachable from the outside. Similarly we find that if more than one strongly connected component with in-degree $0$ exists, no arborescence is possible, as either strongly connected component will not be reachable from the other.

Thus to find such an arborescence, run [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) which takes $O(|V| + |E|)$ time. Loop over all the strongly connected components and find one with in-degree $0$, which takes $O(|V|)$ time. Keep looping and if you find a second one with in-degree $0$, report that an arborescence does not exist.

Once you found the unique strongly connected component with in-degree $0$, simply pick any node in it and construct an arborescence rooted at it using a $O(|V| + |E|)$ depth-first search, as every other node is reachable from this one.